# Rstudio no autocomplete with Rcpp Armadillo?

Tags: c++, r, rstudio, rcpparmadillo

I have long used Rcpp with Rstudio, but recently I lost autocomplete and diagnostic functionality.

I was able to trace the cause to RcppArmadillow.

Here is the basic default c++ new file code with modifications.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector timesTwo(NumericVector x) {
  return x * 2;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double GetValueAt(const NumericMatrix& x, int row = 1, int col = 1) {
  return x(row-1,col-1);
}

/*** R
timesTwo(42)
GetValueAt(as.matrix(42),1,1)
*/
```

This code works and executes correctly. `// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]` even though its commented out is needed and if it is removed or double commented, the code fails at the `x(row-1,col-1);` referance.

I am using `.rs.setClangDiagnostics(2)` for clang diagnostics and I get the following error for running code:

```
error: OpenMP support and version of OpenMP (31, 40 or 45) was disabled in PCH file but is currently enabled
```

And it seems this error is why completion fails.

This has been asked online before, such as here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-does-not-display-correct-c-diagnostics-libclang-error/26439,  https://community.rstudio.com/t/rcpparmadillo-code-completion/41736
https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4685

But it does not look like any of them have a solution that I can replicate. I do not know how I can change PCH file settings or otherwise.

I am using Windows 7 64 bit. R 3.5.3, Rstudio 1.2.5033, with Rtools 3.5 compiler, RcppArmadillo 0.9.850.1.0, All recently updated except R itself.

Code completion does work with just Rcpp and without Armadillo, but basic NumericMatrix functionality is lost. I would like some way to get completion back, either with Armadillo, or get my code to compile with Rcpp and not Armadillo. Thank you.